# How can I smoothly sugar the rim?

Tags: cocktails

Sometimes I end up with a nice even coating of sugar on my lemon drop's rim (it's served in a martini glass). But most of the time the sugar is clumpy and uneven. What can I do to encourage a nice smooth professional coating of sugar on my glass rim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clumps come from too much liquid on the glass when applying the sugar.

The way I learned to salt a glass was to dip the glass upside-down in a shallow plate or bowl of water, let it drip for 5-10 seconds, then dip it into an evenly layered plate of salt.  I think this should work for sugaring a glass.

Answer (score -4):

Also I think use powdered sugar.

Comment: Powdered sugar - or icing sugar - would almost certainly not produce the desired result; you need the crystals in the sugar to stand out, which powdered sugar would not do.